# What change needs to be made to the main function so that each player has exactly three turns?

Tags: python

Currently the players only have one turn each and the winner of the game is never displayed. What change needs to be made to this main function to give each player *exactly* three turns?

```
def main():
    display_welcome()    #1
    number_of_turns = 3
    score_player1 = 0
    score_player2 = 0
    name_player1 = "Olivia"
    name_player2 = "Ned"
    turn_num = 1
    first_player_num = random.randrange(1, number_of_turns + 1)

    if first_player_num == 2:
        temp = name_player1
        name_player1 = name_player2
        name_player2 = temp

    score1 = have_one_turn(turn_num, name_player1)
    score2 = have_one_turn(turn_num, name_player2)

    score_player1 = score_player1 + score1
    score_player2 = score_player2 + score2

    if turn_num < number_of_turns:
        display_turn_results(name_player1, score_player1, name_player2, score_player2, False)     #10
    else:
        display_turn_results(name_player1, score_player1, name_player2, score_player2, True)
```

Comment: `for i in range(3):`?

Comment: can't use a for..in loop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a place to have someone do your homework for you. You're expected to show effort first. Please describe what you've tried so far, and what your understanding of the problem is. For example, can you tell us how the given code currently behaves incorrectly?

Comment: The obvious solution is to call `have_one_turn()` three times for each player.  Is there some reason why you can't do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code ::

```
def main():
    display_welcome()    #1
    number_of_turns = 3
    score_player1 = score_player2 = 0
    name_player1 = "Olivia"
    name_player2 = "Ned"
    first_player_num = random.randrange(1, 2)
    if first_player_num == 2:
        temp = name_player1
        name_player1 = name_player2
        name_player2 = temp
    for turn_num in xrange(3):
        score1 = have_one_turn(turn_num, name_player1)
        score2 = have_one_turn(turn_num, name_player2)
        score_player1 = score_player1 + score1
        score_player2 = score_player2 + score2

        if turn_num+1 < number_of_turns:
            display_turn_results(name_player1, score_player1, 
                                 name_player2, score_player2, False)     #10
        else:
            display_turn_results(name_player1, score_player1, 
                                 name_player2, score_player2, True)
```

If the part of main function can be separated to a different one, recursive function call can be used.

```
def main():
#display function and selecting player to play first.
    game(score1, score2, name_player1, name_player2)
```

The game function can be called the recursively

```
def game(score1, score2, name_player1, name_player2, turn_num=1):
    #calculating score
    number_of_turns = 3 
    turn_num = turn_num+1
    if turn_num < number_of_turns:
        display_turn_results(name_player1, score_player1, 
                             name_player2, score_player2, False)
        game(score_player1, score_player2,  name_player1,
             name_player2, turn_num)
    else:
        display_turn_results(name_player1, score_player1, 
                             name_player2, score_player2, True)
```

Comment: this works but is there another way to do it without using the for...in loop and I just wanna change something but not necessarily add anything, any ideas?

Comment: doesn't seem to be working but this is specifically what the question asks: Make a change to the main() function
Currently the players only have one turn each and the winner of the game is never displayed. 
Change the main() function of this program so that each player has exactly three turns (and 
the turn numbers 1, 2 and 3 are correctly displayed in the output).
So I don't think we can separate the  main function either